# Formatting Time as %d-%m-%y

Tags: python

am trying to print orig_time as 6/9/2013 and running into following error..can anyone provide inputs on what is wrong here

Code:

```
orig_time="2013-06-09 00:00:00"
Time=(orig_time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
print Time
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "date.py", line 2, in <module>
    Time=(orig_time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but the convention is: small letters for variable names and capitalised names for class/type names. Also there's already a module called `time`, so something like `formatted_time` would be even better. (instead of `Time`)

Comment: In general, when SO highlights one of your variable names in cyan or blue, it's probably not a good variable name. (SO's auto-formatter _may_ be wrong about it being a stdlib module/builtin/keyword, but then a human reader may get be mislead for the exact same reason that SO did…)

Answer (score 13):

You cannot use `strftime` on a string as it is not a method of string, one way to do this is by using the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> orig_time="2013-06-09 00:00:00"
#d is a datetime object    
>>> d = datetime.strptime(orig_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Now you can use either string formatting:

```
>>> "{}/{}/{}".format(d.month,d.day,d.year)
'6/9/2013'
```

or [`datetime.datetime.strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
>>> d.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
'06-09-2013'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime("%m-%d-%y",time.strptime("2013-06-09 00:00:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
'06-09-13'
```

but its more of a pain to remove leading zeros ... If you need that use the other answer

also its unclear what you want, since your title says one thing (and your format string), but it does not match what you say is your expected output in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

now1 = time.strftime("%d-%m-%y", time.localtime())
print(now1)
```

If you'd prefer, you can change the "d-m-y" as you want and can use a static time.

Answer (score -1):

```
import time

orig_time="2013-06-09 00:00:00" 

Time= time.strftime(orig_time, '%m-%d-%Y')

print Time
```

Comment: Did you even try this? This does not work. And if you were to fix this, it would be the same as either Ashwini Chaudhary's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17245662/369450) or Joran Beasley's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17245668/369450).